# Finding digamma at an irrational input

Tags: closed-form, digamma-function

I am wondering if it is possible to evaluate the digamma function exactly at certain quadratic irrationals. Specifically I am looking for the values $ \psi \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} \right)$ and $ \psi \left(\frac{\sqrt{5}}{4} \right) $. I know digamma can be evaluated exactly at any rational input using roots of unity, but the derivation depends entirely on the input being rational. Any suggestions for how to deal with quadratic irrational inputs?